# Properly assembling a drinks database with Django (Many to Many)

Tags: python, django, database, many-to-many

I would like to set up a drink database, now I have the problem that the databases are not generated accordingly and I do not know how to do this.

i have already tried several things, but unfortunately no solution was found

how the database should look like:

```
Table 1 (Drinks)

-----------------------------------------------------------
drink_Id |  drink_name  | description | image_path | slug |
-----------------------------------------------------------

Table 2 (ingredients)
---------------------------------
ingredient_id | ingredient_name |
---------------------------------

Table 3 (drink_ratio)
---------------------
ID_ratio | quantity | 
---------------------

Table 4 ()
-----------------------------------------
id | drink_id | ingredient_id | ID_ratio |
-----------------------------------------
```

Code:

```
from django.db import models


class Drinks(models.Model):
    drink_name = models.CharField(max_length=256, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    image_path = models.ImageField(upload_to="./images")
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    ingredient = models.ManyToManyField('ingredient')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.drink_name



class ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, unique=True)

    liquid_ratio = models.ManyToManyField('liquid_ratio')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class liquid_ratio(models.Model):
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2, unique=True)
```

I want to achieve that I have only 4 tables.
like at the top.

A drink can have several ingredients.
A drink can only exist once.

A drink can only have one quantity per ingredient.

THANK YOU :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want a separate `drink_ratio` table. The quantity is a property of the linking element between drink and ingredient, and therefore belongs on the through table (table 4); table 3 isn't required at all. You can model this in Django by using the `through` parameter:

```
class Drink(models.Model):
    drink_name = models.CharField(max_length=256, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    image_path = models.ImageField(upload_to="./images")
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    ingredient = models.ManyToManyField('Ingredient', through='IngredientRatio')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.drink_name   

class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class IngredientRatio(models.Model):
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2, unique=True)
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey('Ingredient', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    drink = models.ForeignKey('Drink', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

(Note, Django models should be named in the singular and with CamelCase.)